# How to set the SSH key of the root user during an automated 20.04 server install?

Tags: server, system-installation, cloud-init

I'm trying to write an SSH key to `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` during an [automated 20.04 server install](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference), but it fails, probably because of permission problems.

The 1st command is successful, the 2nd fails:

```
  late-commands:
    - echo 'test2' > /target/etc/test2
    - echo 'ssh-rsa ...' > /target/root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had the same problem. It would certainly be better to solve this with the `users` block from [could-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html) or `user-data` as mentioned [here](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference#user-data), but I couldn't get either of them to work.

So I went with your solution and added a `mkdir /target/root/.ssh` to the `late-commands`. Not pretty but works.